# How can I change the fill color of data points in multigroup radar chart in r?

Tags: r, plot, graphics, radar-chart

Using r, I would like to change the fill color of the data points in my multi-group radar chart, to indicate which effect sizes are significant versus nonsignificant. 
 
a) Is there a way to change the fill color of individual data points? (ideal solution) 
 
b) Alternatively, is there a way to fill all data points with white, while retaining the original outline colors and line colors? This would allow me to edit the image on a point by point basis outside of r. In the code below, I successfully changed the point type to empty circles using `pty = 1`, but I don't want the lines to show through underneath (practical solution).
Reproducible example:

```
set.seed(1)
df2 <- data.frame(rbind(rep(10, 8), rep(0, 8),
                        matrix(sample(0:10, 24,
                                      replace = TRUE),
                               nrow = 3)))
colnames(df2) <- paste("Var", 1:8)

library(fmsb)

# Fill colors
areas <- c(rgb(1, 0, 0, 0.25),
           rgb(0, 1, 0, 0.25),
           rgb(0, 0, 1, 0.25))

radarchart(df2,
           cglty = 1,       # Grid line type
           cglcol = "gray", # Grid line color
           pcol = 2:4,      # Color for each line
           pty = 1,         # Data point type
           plwd = 2,        # Width for each line
           plty = 1,        # Line type for each line
           pfcol = areas)   # Color of the areas
```

How can I fill the circles with white or keep the lines from showing through?
[image: Example radar chart]

Comment: You could change aspects using the base `par`. Maybe you can set col = "red". by using that.

Comment: @Quinten I don't think this would fill the data points with white, would it?

Comment: The simple way would be to use plot character 21 and specify the fill with `bg=` in the plot command, but that does not work with `radarchart()`. You could try contacting the package maintainer (`maintainer("fmsb")`) to get suggestions. As a fallback hack, you can use `locator()` to identify the points on the plot and then use the `points()` function to over plot them specifying the color and background. It would be nice if `radarchart` returned the coordinates of the points, but that would have to be added to the function.

Comment: @dcarlson Very clever. I didn't know about `locator()` or `points()` -- thank you!